# Site to Site VPN behind a NAT

Tags: azure, site-to-site-vpn

I have a firewall "stormshield" bedind a NAT device, and I would like to establish an Azure site to site VPN, is that possible?

I have already configured it, the VPN connection is established but the traffic is not forwarded, it is not possbie to configure routing in the nat device.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it’s not possible and Microsoft is not working on it.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/5525129-please-make-site-to-site-vpn-avaiable-for-devices

Answer (score 0):

It does work with you have your VPN behind a NAT device. The IKE communication will switch from UDP port 500 to UDP port 4500.

Post the IKE logs and error that you are getting, so that I can help you.

Regards, 
Msrini